# Save Multiselect custom filed on woocommerce product page

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, multi-select, custom-fields

When I try to retrieve data from multiselect custom field I get just the array keys not values like below:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
```

and this is the code of the custom field:

```
function cfwc_create_custom_field() {
    $args = array(
    'id' => 'custom_text_field_title',
    'name' => 'custom_text_field_title[]',
    'label' => __( 'Custom Text Field Title', 'cfwc' ),
    'class' => 'cfwc-custom-field',
    'desc_tip' => true,
    'options'  => array('First', 'Second'),
    'description' => __( 'Enter the title of your custom text field.', 'ctwc' ),
    'custom_attributes' => array('multiple' => 'multiple')
    );
    woocommerce_wp_select( $args );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'cfwc_create_custom_field' );

function cfwc_save_custom_field( $post_id ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $title = isset( $_POST['custom_text_field_title'] ) ? $_POST['custom_text_field_title'] : '';
    $product->update_meta_data( 'custom_text_field_title',  $_POST['custom_text_field_title'] );
    $product->save();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'cfwc_save_custom_field' );
```

Comment: This will not work as your multi-select field is posting only the last selected value when you make multiple selections… You need to make a custom multi select field html…

Comment: A little bit confusing!

Answer (score 0):

I think you issue is with you woocommerce_wp_select options you provided, as you have used the option array('First', 'Second') as there is no key provided it simply return 0,1 value as array. So if you want key then you have to provide it for Ex: `array('First' => 'First', 'Second' => 'Second')` or key just lowercase whichever you like.

```
function cfwc_create_custom_field() {
    $args = array(
    'id' => 'custom_text_field_title',
    'name' => 'custom_text_field_title[]',
    'label' => __( 'Custom Text Field Title', 'cfwc' ),
    'class' => 'cfwc-custom-field',
    'desc_tip' => true,
    'options'  => array('First' => 'First', 'Second' => 'Second'), // this is correct
    'description' => __( 'Enter the title of your custom text field.', 'ctwc' ),
    'custom_attributes' => array('multiple' => 'multiple')
    );
    woocommerce_wp_select( $args );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'cfwc_create_custom_field' );

function cfwc_save_custom_field( $post_id ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $title = isset( $_POST['custom_text_field_title'] ) ? $_POST['custom_text_field_title'] : '';
    $product->update_meta_data( 'custom_text_field_title',  $_POST['custom_text_field_title'] );
    $product->save();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'cfwc_save_custom_field' );
```

Comment: Yes I tried that but i get the same thing